# retry on exception code results in compiler warning

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am having trouble with my retry code.
Here is a trimmed down version of my code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim var As String
    Dim retries As Integer = 0
    Dim wasSuccess As Boolean = False

    Do
        Try
            var = "test"
            wasSuccess = True
        Catch
            If retries = 0 Then
                retries = 1
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End Try
    Loop Until wasSuccess

    Console.Write(var)
End Sub
```

The problem is I get a compile warning on the variable var the first time I reference it after the do loop code block as "used before assigned a value"

Any suggestion as to how to prevent this?

Comment: What is _var_? ..

Comment: `var` is not declared in the code we can see

Comment: So, if I understand your problem, the error happens after you exit from this code? Then you should provide that part of your the code (and include also the declaration of _var_)r

Comment: yes var is declared, I just didn't show it in my code above.  I'ts an object so I declare it but don't give it a value.  That is the job of that function that sometimes has an exception.

Comment: OK, I've edited my code example above to be a complete example.  It now shows all declarations and usages.

Answer (score 1):

Compile warning is not error. Although, in your project options you have option "treat warnings as errors". If that is selected, your compilation will fail. Uncheck it if you like. The error caused by `Console.Write(var)`. Because for vb compiler, it is uncertain that assignment will happen under `Try`-block. Hence it treats that line and `var` in it as never assigned. If you do `Dim var As String = String.Empty`, it should go away.

**Following part** is referring to OP original code. OP changed code since
You code just doesn't seem right to me. Should be like this

```
Dim maxAttempts As Integer = 10
Dim attempts As Integer = 0

While Not success
    attempts += 1
    Try
        result = SubThatSumtimesResultsInException()
        success = True
    Catch
    End Try

    If attempts = maxAttempts Then Exit While
End While
```

Although, as discussion, you can restructure where instead of `success = True` you can place `Exit While` because frankly, if you hit that line, you have success. But then again, you my need to keep `success` because exit loop in either way, you will be able to tell if it was successful, hence I keep it.

Comment: The while look has the same problem as the do loop.

Comment: @Chestdawg There is NO problem in the while loop. It is somewhere else

Comment: Logically the while loop works.  So does the do loop.  In practice however Visual Studio can't follow the logic and throw a compile time warning.